# Send Requests from Domain to Specific Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I have a single rails app running on a Rackspace VPS. The stack is rails3 + unicorn + nginx + mysql.

There is a primary domain that sends traffic directly to the unicorn socket using [`proxy_pass`](https://github.com/spree/deployment_service_puppet/blob/master/modules/nginx/templates/sites-available/site.erb#L26).

I have a new engine developed that's mounted under `/digital`. Right now, people can interact with that engine via http://primarydomain.com/digital.

I want to host a new domain that forwards requests directly to `/digital`; not to the root engine.

So for instance, the following requests would yield equivilent results:

http://primarydomain.com/digital/splash
http://alternatedomain.com/splash

In a perfect world, the engine would be a separate app. I want to act as if the separate domain is a separate app although it's really a mounted engine.

Here's what the `routes.rb` looks like:

```
Company::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'spree/home#splash'

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  mount Core::Engine, :at => '/'
  mount Another::Engine, :at => '/digital'
end
```

What rails + nginx configuration do I need to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to solve this is using route constraints within Rails. In fact, having the parts of your app in engines makes it even simpler.

```
Company::Application.routes.draw do

  mount Core::Engine,    at: '/', constraints: { domain: 'coredomain.com' }
  mount Another::Engine, at: '/', constraints: { domain: 'anotherdomain.com' }

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

end
```

Make sure the engine mounts come first in the routes so that their routes take preference over whatever `ActiveAdmin` adds.

Now you just need to point both domains at the app with nginx and you're good to go.

You may even mount `Another::Engine` twice if you want to keep it working under `coredomain.com/digital` too:

```
Company::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints domain: 'coredomain.com' do
    mount Core::Engine, at: '/'
    mount Another::Engine, at: '/digital'
  end

  constraints domain: 'anotherdomain.com' do
    mount Another::Engine, at: '/'
  end

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

end
```