# default_url_options for Routes Specified in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Rails 3.2.x app with two primary engines serving requests from two separate domains using [this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931693/send-requests-from-domain-to-specific-rails-engine):

```
Company::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints host: ENV['DOMAIN_ONE'] do
    mount Core::Engine, :at => '/'
  end

  constraints host: ENV['DOMAIN_TWO'] do
    mount Another::Engine, at: '/'
  end
end
```

I need to reference a route in `Another::Engine` from a page in `Core::Engine`, for example:

```
<%= link_to "A Link", another.a_route_url %>
```

However, when I the URL helper method does not generate the full URL with the domain of `Another::Engine`; instead the helper uses the domain of `Core::Engine`.

I'm guessing that the `default_url_options` are automatically set somewhere in the bowels of the `Rails::Engine` code and automatically set the `host` option based on the engine's routing constraints. My hunch is when *any* helper is called within a action inside that engine – even if it's a URL helper in another engine – the helper inherits the current engine's `default_url_options`.

Is there a way to force all routes specified in a another engine to use a different `host` parameter without passing the `host` parameter directly to the helper (i.e. `another.a_route_url(host: ENV['DOMAIN_TWO'])`)?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're unable to use the suggested practice of the engine.named_route because it is conflicting with the other engine mounted at the root as well? When mounting engines the engine routes are accessible under <rubygem>_engine.new_sessions_path, for example. Having recently looked through all of this when creating an engine, the Rails routes exist on Rails.application.routes (RouteSet). I don't know if that helps much.

Comment: No, I use `another.route_url` just fine, but the full URL returned uses the `host` of the current engine rather than the `host` specified in `routes` for the  `another` engine

Comment: any more success? Can you use the initializers inside the rails engine?

Answer (score 2):

Looked into this and here's the best solution I could find:

```
# engine_route_modifier.rb
class EngineRouteModifier
  def initialize(proxy, opts = {})
    @options = opts
    @proxy = proxy
  end

  def method_missing(method_sym, *arguments, &block)
    extracted_url_options = arguments.extract_options!

    @options.each do |k,v|
      if !extracted_url_options.has_key?(k)
        extracted_url_options[k] = v
      end
    end

    arguments << extracted_url_options

    @proxy.send(method_sym, *arguments)
  end
end

# application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def core_proxy
    @core_proxy ||= EngineRouteModifier.new(core, host: ENV['DOMAIN_ONE'])
  end

  def another_proxy
    @another_proxy ||= EngineRouteModifier.new(another, host: ENV['ANOTHER_DOMAIN'])
  end
end
```